# mysql optimizatin

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, indexing

I would like to ask you for help with optimizing part of an e-shop application. I have a database running on MySQL and I am struggling with performance when doing large product imports. In particular, have the following tables (omitting unimportant fields):

This is table of products that are available in the store. Except for this info, it also contains price, cost, dimensions and other things that are not important right now approximate size 15,000 rows.

```
product {
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `codemaster_id` int(16) NOT NULL
}
```

This table sets configurations of all vehicle ever made approximate size 500,000 rows.

```
vehicle_superconfig {
  `EngineConfigID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EngineDesignationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineVINID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValvesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineBaseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FuelDeliveryConfigID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AspirationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CylinderHeadTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FuelTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IgnitionSystemTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineMfrID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineVersionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PowerOutputID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BaseVehicleID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SubmodelID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SteeringConfigID` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `DriveTypeID` int(10) NOT NULL,
}
```

This table sets requirements for the part to be applicable in a vehicle (e.g. that this screw comes into BMW 328i with this type of engine available in Europe only, that it requires some other parts to be pre-installed etc. If there are no requirements for the particular area, the attribute is set to 0 (e.g. side mirror does not care whether the car engine runs on gas or diesel or anything else). approximate size 10,000 rows.

```
product_application{
  `ID` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `basevehicle_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `submodel_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EngineConfigID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EngineDesignationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineVINID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValvesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineBaseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FuelDeliveryConfigID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AspirationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CylinderHeadTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FuelTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IgnitionSystemTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineMfrID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EngineVersionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PowerOutputID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BaseVehicleID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SubmodelID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SteeringConfigID` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `DriveTypeID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  ... several other fields that are not used in the queries here
}

// this table determines what kind of part we have
// and where it belongs (e.g. that it is a mirror on right side)
// approximate size 30,000 rows
part_codemaster { 
  `codemaster_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `part_type` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(8) NOT NULL,
}
```

The application obtains vehicle specification, determines the the vehicle_id and engine config and is supposed to list the parts that fit this vehicle. position is included as certain products fit many places (e.g. screws) I need to fill this table with missing connections (for approximately 500 new products in table product) based on the the data in the tables above.

```
product_to_vehicle {
  `ID` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `engine_config_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(8) NOT NULL
}
```

My task, as said, is to fill in missing connections into table product_to_vehicle for the newly imported products. My question is how to do it in a reasonable time (let us say under 1 hour - this query will be run on command line once a week or so when the new updates are in). In particular, I am interested in:

- Is my query somehow dumb? How to write it better?
- What indices should I generate for the tables? My guess is that index for every column is not enough...
- What type of tables (InnoDB or MyISAM) should I use?
- Is there anything else that could help?

The query I use now is:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
    product_to_vehicle(product_id, vehicle_id, engine_config_id, position) (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        att.product_id,
        sup.vehicle_id,
        sup.engine_config_id,
        c.position as position
    FROM
        product_application as att,
        vehicle_super as sup,
        product as p,
        codemaster as c
    WHERE p.product_id > 10000 AND p.product_id < 10500
      AND (sup.base_vehicle_id = att.base_vehicle_id OR att.base_vehicle_id = 0)
      AND (sup.submodel_id = att.submodel_id OR att.submodel_id = 0)
      AND (att.AspirationID = sup.AspirationID OR att.AspirationID = 0)
      AND (att.DriveTypeID = sup.DriveTypeID OR att.DriveTypeID = 0)
      AND (att.CylinderHeadTypeID = sup.CylinderHeadTypeID OR att.CylinderHeadTypeID =  0)
      AND (att.FuelTypeID = sup.FuelTypeID OR att.FuelTypeID = 0)
      AND (p.CodeMasterID = c.CodeMasterID)
      AND (att.ProductID = p.product_id)
  );
COMMIT;
```

I had the query running for a single product (with p.product_id = 10000) for about 4 hours now and it still did not finish. I will be happy for any suggestion.

Comment: Create index keys for every field you use in the where clause. That should speed things up a bit.

Comment: MyISAM and InnoDB are engines. Instead of so many conditions in `WHERE`, use `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: your joins are strange, why the or = 0?